Fix "bundle initial exceeded maximum budget" error in an NX monorepo library
I have created a NX monorepo workspace in which I have a nx.json file and a project.json for each library in the "libs" folder.
When I try to build the whole project I get the following error:
Warning: /<my-workspace>/libs/layout/src/lib/components/panel/panel.component.scss exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.05 kB was not met by 1.55 kB with a total of 3.60 kB.

Warning: /<my-workspace>/libs/messenger/src/lib/components/messages-viewer/messages-viewer.component.scss exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.05 kB was not met by 122 bytes with a total of 2.17 kB.

Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 512.00 kB was not met by 938.53 kB with a total of 1.45 MB.

Error: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 1.05 MB was not met by 401.95 kB with a total of 1.45 MB.

Since I used the latest version of NX (@nx/angular 19.4.4) I don't have any workspace.json nor angular.json file in my workspace that could make me to solve this.
So, where to put settings like the following?
"budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "500kb",
      "maximumError": "1mb"
    },
    {
      "type": "anyComponentStyle",
      "maximumWarning": "2kb",
      "maximumError": "4kb"
    }
]

If I try to add it to project.json file of every library I get the following error:
NX   'budgets' is not found in schema
So, how to fix the error?
Here is how I have tried to add budget array to one of project.json file:
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:package",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "project": "libs/messenger/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/messenger/tsconfig.lib.prod.json",
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/messenger/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
...
}


You can find it on your project.json file
project.json
targets -->  <build-target> --> configurations --> <enviroment-name> --> budgets

I have edited my question adding a part of project.json file. If I add the budgets array as you described I get "budgets' is not found in schema" error...

I discovered that adding budgets property works for project.json of any application of apps, but it doesn't work for project.json of a library. Why?!?

Most of the times libraries are not meant to be built separately, they are meant to be used in a project
